# Is it possible to subtract a number from inline style injected by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an inline style added to the HTML, like `style="left: 10px;"`. Can I add/subtract to that number?

I would like to create a rule where I can remove `8px` from that number no matter what that number is.

I tried using the ugly `!important` hack to override it, but that doesn't help when the initial value is changed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From 1.6 onwards, you can use the convenient:

```
$('#myelem').css('left','-=8px')
```

If for some strange reason you are stuck in the past, use:

```
$('#myelem').css('left', function(i,v) {
    return v - 8;
});
```

for jQuery 1.4 up.

Comment: Didn't know that, nice one :-).

Comment: It should be `$('#myelem').css('left', function(index, value) {` and return `value - 8`. Right now you are subtracting the index and not the `left` value.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use `margin-left -8px` instead. I don't know what you are looking for, but it might do the trick without JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with this, javascript shouldn't be used for amending layout.

Comment: I would prefer to handle something like this with css but in-line styles have priority over embed styles, I kind of have to manipulate the JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

There is no [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) rule for such. However, you can do the same using [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Assume you have,

```
.my_left {
   left: 10px;
}
```

And [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) elements like below,

```
<div class="my_left">My Div</div>
<div class="my_left">My Div</div>
```

Then using the below script, you can remove `8px` from its current `left` value:

```
$(function () {
   $('.my_left').css('left', function (i, ov) {
       return ov - 8;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable for it, in order to be able to add or subtract:

```
var x=10;

x=x-parseInt(5);

x=x+parseInt(5);

<div id='something' style="left: "+x+"px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently found on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) that you can override inline css with

```
.myClassName[style] {
   left:5px!important;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/