# Increase a value on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Every time I click on a button I want its z-index to increase one by one. How can I do it?

```
$('#Box').css('z-index', 'newindex');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to substract a number from inline style injected by Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568687/is-it-possible-to-substract-a-number-from-inline-style-injected-by-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

For [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) 1.6 and later, use:

```
$('#Box').css('z-index','+=1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#Box').css('z-index',$('#Box').css('z-index') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the -ve but say why please.

Answer (score 0):

Read the index. Add one to the index. Reset the index with the new value.

```
var myElem = $('#Box');
var currentIndex = myElem.css('z-index') || 0;
myElem.css('z-index', currentIndex+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.css` method both to get *and* set a particular value.

Since you want to take the current value and increment it, you would first use `$('#Box').css('z-index')` to get the value, then you would increment it and pass it to `$('#Box').css('z-index', newvalue)`.